# How to Google Pay is showing different type of cards in the grid view of Your Rewards page

Tags: java, android

I want to know how Google pay is showing a different type of cards in the grid view of Your Rewards page. I'm trying to dev.elop cards like Google Pay

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available for developing scratch card functionality like Google Pay

[Check this](https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/android-scratch-card-view/)

```
implementation 'com.goibibo.libs:scratchcardview:0.1.4'
```

XML looks like below

```xml
<com.goibibo.libs.views.ScratchTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:text="@string/flat_200"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
```

Also, Check this [Blog post](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView)

I hope this may help you,

Comment: Thank you, Mehul Solanki. I have already done with what this can do. But the real problem is how to show the unscratched cards in the rewards Gridview.

Comment: I used `CardView` for that.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me. If u have any example let me see. Thanks.